# How to avoid default attendee in sharepoint2010 team site workspace

Tags: 2010, meeting-workspace, settings

If I create a meeting workspace on Sharepoint2010 site, I'm by default added as an attendee to every new meeting in that workspace.

Can I avoid this in any way? I need no default attendees.

Comment: I have been looking for how to do this as well... has anyone posted a response?